# Game navigation disabled after changing Quality settings

Tags: unity

Just installed Unity 2019.11.f1(Personal)[Window10/64bit-Dx11 on Dx10] and ran the sample *"Lightweight rendering pipeline"* Construction Project.

At the start,the game navigation keys [W-A-S-D] worked **but the navigation was slow.**
So on changing the Quality settings[Edit-ProjectSettings-Quality] **from  default "High" to "Low",** the **game navigation keys have got disabled** and the console throws the following error-

```
Converting invalid MinMaxAABB
```

On reverting back to the working "High" quality settings , **the navigation controls no longer work.**
How to resolve this issue?
[image]

Comment: If you repeat the same steps on a new project, does the same behaviour occur?

Comment: Yeah,Nav controls do work on a New Project .My guess is the errors were possibly due to the additional installed assets like Shader & Vfx graph which were added to the sample project .Since it is a Dx10 Gpu ,probably there are some compatibility issues in Lwrp projects with these assets.

Comment: This is very important information that should be somewhere on the question. Otherwise others will try to guess if something went wrong while installing Unity, which seems like is not the issue here.

Comment: This is not an Answer but just a Guess .Any ways, if some one refers to this question ,they most probably will read this comment. If required ,this issue could be closed by posting the above comment as an answer.

Comment: The problem is its not an answer. New people reading this question, shouldn't have to go through the comments to complete the question. Keep in mind users here are volunteers, and if they read a question that is missing important details, they will most likely skip it, without even reaching the comments. If your issue is being created by installing additional packages in a project, then edit your question to focus on that problem.

Comment: Every InstalledPackage and ChangedFeature which has nothing to do with the problem, cannot be incorporated into the question.Its misleading to point someone to a package or a setting as a culprit ,when the solution is  just a GUESS.What if people stop installing those packages based on the Edited question ? Also Unity is littered with issues ,just look at the Console (image) ,there are so many bugs/errors . How can you say that the problem is not because of these other issues ? Until Unity resolves these issues and its clear where the problem lies ,it would be a bad idea to Edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE**- *Reader's are requested to check performance of the below mentioned Packages in their own LWRP(light weight rendering pipeline) project,before not installing/uninstalling them.*

Eventhough Unity's new **Vfx/Shader Graph info shows support for LWRP projects** in the Package Manager ,but if the computer's **GPU does not support DX11**(eg Dx11 on Dx10),some issues/errors
may occur which may not be obvious.

> **Obvious error's**

***Shader Graph***

`Compute shaders not supported on Gpu`

***Vfx Graph***

```
Vfx rendering requires compute shaders,no rendering will occur.
```

> ***Weird Issues***

However,along with no support for Shader/Vfx Graph ,there are some weird issues.

-**Game Navigation Controls (W-A-S-D)get disabled**,resulting in complete stalling of  development.

-Also,following ***error*** is repeatedly thrown by the console

```
Converting invalid MinMaxAABB
```

However,on **uninstalling the Vfx and Shader graph packages from the LWRP project** , the game runs fine.